# how to add mouse events to force directed graph using the d3 canvas renderer?

Tags: javascript, events, d3.js, click, mouse

All the other examples have mouse events with svg.append().... I don't know where to "enter" to get the arcs in a canvas renderer and add `.on('click', function(){})` in v4 style. I want to click to get the value of `d`. Where do I add the handler in this example? I understand the old way below this example.

Might something like this work? `d3.select(canvas).call(d3.mouse()).on("click", ...)`

link to [working example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/95aa92e2f4e8345aaa55a4a94d41ce37)

```
var links = d3.range(nodes.length - 1).map(function(i) {
  return {
    source: Math.floor(Math.sqrt(i)),
    target: i + 1
  };
});

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).distance(20).strength(1))
    .force("x", d3.forceX())
    .force("y", d3.forceY())
    .on("tick", ticked);

var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    width = canvas.width,
    height = canvas.height;

d3.select(canvas)
    .call(d3.drag()
        .container(canvas)
        .subject(dragsubject)
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended));

function ticked() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  context.save();
  context.translate(width / 2, height / 2);

  context.beginPath();
  links.forEach(drawLink);
  context.strokeStyle = "#aaa";
  context.stroke();

  context.beginPath();
  nodes.forEach(drawNode);
  context.fill();
  context.strokeStyle = "#fff";
  context.stroke();

  context.restore();
}

function dragsubject() {
  return simulation.find(d3.event.x - width / 2, d3.event.y - height / 2);
}

function dragstarted() {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d3.event.subject.fx = d3.event.subject.x;
  d3.event.subject.fy = d3.event.subject.y;
}

function dragged() {
  d3.event.subject.fx = d3.event.x;
  d3.event.subject.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended() {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d3.event.subject.fx = null;
  d3.event.subject.fy = null;
}

function drawLink(d) {
  context.moveTo(d.source.x, d.source.y);
  context.lineTo(d.target.x, d.target.y);
}

function drawNode(d) {
  context.moveTo(d.x + 3, d.y);
  context.arc(d.x, d.y, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
}
```

**old way**

```
var node = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "nodes")
.selectAll("circle")
.data(graph.nodes)
.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 8)
  .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
  .on("click", togglenode)
  .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended));
```

Answer (score 3):

In D3 v4.x, you add a click event pretty much the same way you do in v3.x:

```
selection.on("click", function(d){
    //do whatever you want with the datum
});
```

The problem in your question is not v3 versus v4, that's not the issue in the code you shared. The problem with that code is that it uses HTML **canvas**, not SVG, to render the dataviz.

Unlike SVG, canvas doesn't have a node tree of elements. You cannot "select something" and add an event handler to it.

Think of canvas as a raster image, like a BMP or a JPEG. You can find on what x and y position you clicked, you can even find the colour of that pixel, but you cannot select a given node element, because canvas has none.

For instance, check this [tutorial from Nadieh Bremer](http://www.visualcinnamon.com/2015/11/learnings-from-a-d3-js-addict-on-starting-with-canvas.html) to see how complicated is to get the circle the user clicks on when you use HTML canvas.

Comment: surely there's a proper way with canvas to do d3.mouse() or something? I ended up using the start drag from d3.drag() module on canvas. I would imagine it simply transforms global mouse coordinates into the coordinate space of the canvas.

Answer (score 2):

Since I used the canvas renderer, I just cheated and used the d3 dragstart event already in the example. There's probably a way to do it like this I'd like to know.

```
        d3.select(canvas)
        .call(d3.drag()
            .container(canvas)
            .subject(dragsubject)
            .on("start", dragstarted)
            .on("drag", dragged)
            .on("end", dragended));

function dragstarted(d) {
            if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d3.event.subject.fx = d3.event.subject.x;
            d3.event.subject.fy = d3.event.subject.y;
            //broadcast the selection to parent
            emitter.emit( d3.event.subject );
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanded FlavorScape's hack with double click

```
        d3.select(canvas)
        .call(d3.drag()
            .container(canvas)
            .subject(dragsubject)
            .on("start", dragstarted)
            .on("drag", dragged)
            .on("end", dragended));
        var clickDate = new Date();
        var difference_ms;
        function dragstarted(d) {
            if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d3.event.subject.fx = d3.event.subject.x;
            d3.event.subject.fy = d3.event.subject.y;
            difference_ms = (new Date()).getTime() - clickDate.getTime();
            clickDate = new Date();
            //if clicks less than 200ms apart (double click)
            if(difference_ms < 200)
                console.log( d3.event.subject );
        }
```