# D3 double-click to reset the sticky nodes

Tags: d3.js

I want to reset my canvas sticky nodes to its original position when it is double clicked. I am adding the following code to [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/46e300b5f2ad4af350fbd01ffec3e25d) but it does not work :

```
function dblclick() {
  graph.nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.fx = d.fy = null;
 })
};
```

Adding `dblclick` to the nodes :

```
simulation
  .nodes(graph.nodes)
  .on("tick", ticked)
  .on("dblclick", dblclick);
```

In the following example when the node is double-clicked, it gets reset to its original position, however, this example is in SVG.

[Sticky Force Layout](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a modified version of [Andrew's force layout](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/46e300b5f2ad4af350fbd01ffec3e25d) which frees sticky nodes when double clicked:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    width = canvas.width,
    height = canvas.height;

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/4062045/raw/5916d145c8c048a6e3086915a6be464467391c62/miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  d3.select(canvas)
      .call(d3.drag()
          .container(canvas)
          .subject(dragsubject)
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

  function ticked() {
    var margin = 20;
    graph.nodes.forEach(function(d) { 
      d.x = Math.max(margin, Math.min(width - margin, d.x))
      d.y = Math.max(margin, Math.min(height - margin, d.y))
    })
  
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    context.beginPath();
    graph.links.forEach(drawLink);
    context.strokeStyle = "#aaa";
    context.stroke();

    context.beginPath();
    graph.nodes.forEach(drawNode);
    context.fill();
    context.strokeStyle = "#fff";
    context.stroke();
  }

  function dragsubject() {
    return simulation.find(d3.event.x, d3.event.y);
  }
});

var clickDate = new Date();
var difference_ms;

function dragstarted() {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d3.event.subject.fx = Math.max(10, Math.min(width - 10, d3.event.subject.x));
  d3.event.subject.fy = Math.max(10, Math.min(height - 10, d3.event.subject.y));
}

function dragged() {
  d3.event.subject.fx = Math.max(10, Math.min(width - 10, d3.event.x));
  d3.event.subject.fy = Math.max(10, Math.min(height - 10, d3.event.y));
}

function dragended() {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);

  difference_ms = (new Date()).getTime() - clickDate.getTime();
  clickDate = new Date();
  if (difference_ms < 200) {
    simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart()
    d3.event.subject.fx = null;
    d3.event.subject.fy = null;
  }
}
function drawLink(d) {
  context.moveTo(d.source.x, d.source.y);
  context.lineTo(d.target.x, d.target.y);
}

function drawNode(d) {
  context.moveTo(d.x + 3, d.y);
  context.arc(d.x, d.y, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<canvas width="700" height="550"></canvas>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

This is a direct application of this [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48446566/9297144) which adds a simili double click listener by using in our case the `dragended` part of the drag listeners.

Here is the modified `dragended` function:

```
function dragended() {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);

  // Time between 2 ends of drag:
  difference_ms = (new Date()).getTime() - clickDate.getTime();
  clickDate = new Date();
  // if the time between these 2 ends of drag is short enough, then
  // it's considered a double click:
  if (difference_ms < 200) {
    // And we can release the node:
    simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart()
    d3.event.subject.fx = null;
    d3.event.subject.fy = null;
  }
}
```

The idea consists in having a global variable which stores the date of the last time an element has been dragended, in order to know, the next time the dragended is triggered again, how much time it's been since the last trigger.

And thus by setting a maximum time threshold (e.g. 200ms) between two dragended, we can determine that we're in a double click situation.

Once we've determined it's a double click, then we can release the constraint on the clicked node by resetting it's force settings:

```
simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart()
d3.event.subject.fx = null;
d3.event.subject.fy = null;
```